# Odoo workflows wrong transitions

Tags: python, workflow, transition, state, odoo-8

I have added two new states to the mrp.production workflow. 'new_state' comming right after the 'draft' state and 'new_done_state' which replaces the 'done' state. We I make a transition to 'new_state' (by clicking a button) the workflows goes from draft > new_done_state and then from new_done_state > new_state. I can't seem to understand this. Can someone pls explain this.

This is my models.py code

```
class nametingen_mrp_production(models.Model):
_inherit = ['mrp.production']

state = fields.Selection([
                          ('draft', 'New'), 
                          ('new_state', 'new state'), 
                          ('cancel', 'Cancelled'), 
                          ('confirmed', 'Awaiting Raw Materials'), 
                          ('ready', 'Ready to Produce'), 
                          ('in_production', 'Production Started'), 
                          ('new_done_state', 'new done state')]
                         , 'State')
def action_new_state(self):
    self.write({'state': 'new_state'})    
    return True    

def action_new_done_state(self):
    self.write({'state': 'new_done_state'})
    return True
```

This is my views.xml

```
<record id="manufacturing_order_form_change" model="ir.ui.view"> 
    <field name="name">manufacturing.order.form.change</field> 
    <field name="model">mrp.production</field> 
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_form_view"/> 
    <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
        <field name="state" position="replace">
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,new_state,confirmed,ready,in_production,new_done_state" statusbar_colors='{"confirmed":"blue"}'/>
        </field>

        <field name="state" position="before">
                <!-- From draft to new state -->
                <button string="Send to new state" name="signal_new_state" states="draft" class="oe_highlight"/>

                <!-- From new state to Confirmed state-->
                <button string="Confirm" name="signal_confirmed" states="new_state" class="oe_highlight"/>

                <!-- From in production to new_done_state-->
                <button string="done" name="signal_new_done_state" states="in_production" class="oe_highlight"/>

        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

My workflows.xml

```
   <!-- ACTIVITIES -->
    <record id="prod_act_new_state" model="workflow.activity">               
            <field name="name">new_state</field>                        
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="mrp.wkf_prod"/>   
            <field name="kind">function</field> 
            <field name="action">action_new_staten()</field>  
            <field name="flow_start">False</field>
    </record> 
    <record id="prod_act_new_done_state" model="workflow.activity">               
            <field name="name">new_done_state</field>                        
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="mrp.wkf_prod"/>   
            <field name="kind">function</field> 
            <field name="action">action_new_done_state()</field> 
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
    </record> 
    <!-- TRANSITIONS -->
    <record id="prod_trans_done_new_state" model="workflow.transition">       
            <field name="act_from" ref="mrp.prod_act_draft"/>               
            <field name="act_to" ref="prod_act_new_state"/>
            <field name="signal">signal_new_state</field>                                                             
    </record>   
    <record id="prod_trans_new_state_confirmed" model="workflow.transition">       
            <field name="act_from" ref="prod_act_new_state"/>               
            <field name="act_to" ref="mrp.prod_act_confirmed"/>
             <field name="signal">signal_confirmed</field>                                                             
    </record> 
    <record id="prod_trans_inproduction_new_done_state" model="workflow.transition">       
            <field name="act_from" ref="mrp.prod_act_in_production"/>               
            <field name="act_to" ref="prod_act_new_done_state"/>
            <field name="signal">signal_new_done_state</field>                                                             
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "type" attribute to your new buttons and set it as "workflow".
Example:

```
<button string="Send to new state" name="signal_new_state" type="workflow" states="draft" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

Comment: I resolved it in another way, but I will definitely try this in the future because I do think this could help. Thanks!